# strongloop/loopback - Maintain multiple versions of API

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using strongloop/loopback for the first time. There is some rudimentary instruction [online](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Versioning+your+API) for versioning an API:

```
var p = require('../package.json');
var version = p.version.split('.').shift();
module.exports = {
  restApiRoot: '/api' + (version > 0 ? '/v' + version : ''),
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000
};
```

What I don't see, is a recommended way of maintaining multiple versions of an API. So, for example, I could have a legacy 1.4 version and new 2.0 version running at the same time. Is there a best practice for doing so?

**Edit:** I have accepted @Overdrivr's answer as it is accurate at time of writing. However, there is an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2483) regarding this feature with a user planning to submit a PR. Hopefully this functionality will be added in a future iteration.

Comment: Hopefully, when [Loopback will support GraphGL](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1841) it should become a whole lot more easier to maintain multiple API versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to run two loopback servers, one running 1.4 and the other 2.0. Make one listen on port 3000 and the other on 3001 for instance.

Then you can use nginx as reverse-proxy.

nginx will listen to port 80 or 443 (http or https), the port that your clients will reach.
Finally, tell nginx to re-route requests matching `/api/v1.4/` to server 1.4 and `/api/v2/` to the other.

Comment: Can you please put a bit more details into this?
(Sorry, doing this for the first time)
Which NGinx version to use here?
And how will both the version run at the same time on a heroku installation?

Comment: I doubt you can do this with heroku, you need routing capabilities like you can get in google cloud or aws. I haven't tried this myself so I cannot provide a lot more info, it's more of a principle really

Comment: An easy solution would be to host both APIs on subdomains. `apiv1.yourapp.com` and `apiv2.yourapp.com`. In that case you can deploy each version to a different heroku project

Comment: I ultimately ended up using two different Heroku apps for these versions. How I wish it was easier done in loopback, and that we always have to start with v1 whenever we begin coding in loopback. Thanks for your help though!