# LoopBack API Versioning

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have to go through the link [LoopBack API Versioning](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Versioning-your-API.html).

But exactly not understand the proper way to how to do API versioning. Anyone have worked on that. Can u please explain or provide more detail Please.

Comment: Did you try what is recommended in the article without success? Try something and tell what is a problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. When I change the API Version Ex: 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 then all API changed from /API/v1 to /API/v2. It's work as given document. but the problem is what about the old APIs?. What about my old users that follow /API/v1?.
Thanks.

Comment: Hope reading of this question, answer, comments and links there - [Maintain multiple versions of API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883944/strongloop-loopback-maintain-multiple-versions-of-api) - will help to get what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, @Serge, I will check.